# Python OpenCV IndexError

Tags: python

I`m writing my programm in Python. Here is a code:

```
from cv2 import cv2

img = cv2.imread("1.png")

print("Высота:"+str(img.shape[0]))
print("Ширина:" + str(img.shape[1]))
print("Количество каналов:" + str(img.shape[2]))

for x in str(img.shape[0]):
    for y in str(img.shape[1]):
        if img[x, y] == (255, 255, 255):
            img[x, y] = (255, 0, 0)

cv2.imwrite("result.png", img)
```

And I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Projects\Captcha Decrypt\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    if img[x, y] == (255, 255, 255):
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Can you solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the contents of shape but you are iterating over a string because you converted it to `str`. I think you have to convert `x` and `y` to `int` to make it work.

```
for x in str(img.shape[0]):
    for y in str(img.shape[1]):
        if img[int(x), int(y)] == (255, 255, 255):
            img[int(x), int(y)] = (255, 0, 0)
```